# Как получить все значения n-го количества объектов из массива

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть массив, в нём есть объекты, объектов в массиве несколько, сколько именно не известно и они динамически изменяются. Единственное что известно это ключ в каждом объекте который нужно получить.
Вот как сделать так, чтобы значения этих ключей выводились в какой-то блок все сразу.

Comment: _объектов в массиве несколько, сколько именно не известно_ - известно: свойство `length` показывает количество элементов в массиве

Comment: Массив же динамически наполняется и каждый раз его длинна разная

Comment: @МаксимЗакшевский, ну и свойство `length` меняется при добавлении/удалении элементов в массив.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если нужно лишь получить новый массив, в котором будут значения объектов старого массива по соответствующему ключу, то может помочь функция [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
let array = [
    {keyName: '123', anotherKey: 'whatever'},
    {keyName: 'abc'},
    {keyName: '777'}
];
let arrayOfKeys = array.map(object => object['keyName']);
console.log(arrayOfKeys);
```

Если надо ещё и добавить эти значения в некоторый блок, то можно и без функции `map`, с помощью цикла [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of). Добавить значения в некоторый блок можно, например, с помощью jquery и функции [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/).

```js
let array = [
    {keyName: '123', anotherKey: 'whatever'},
    {keyName: 'abc'},
    {keyName: '777'}
];

for (let element of array) {
    let value = element['keyName'];
    $('#blockWhereValuesWillBeAdded').append(`<p>${value}</p>`);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="blockWhereValuesWillBeAdded"></div>
```

Comment: попробуй писать более развернутые ответы

Comment: @Grundy, это очень хороший совет. Просто это простой вопрос, и если сразу писать развёрнутый ответ, то кто-нибудь наверняка ответит раньше, и наполовину написанный развёрнутый ответ будет не нужен.

Comment: Хорошо написанный развернутый ответ нужен всегда!

Comment: @Дмитрий спасибо. Последний вариант очень хорош.